# Problems downloading file using HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-406

Im having problems doing something as simple as downloading a file using HttpClient.

When ever execute "GetByteArrayAsync", i get an error stating: "Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable)."

What am i doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        byte[] fileBytes = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(@"http://url.com/filename.png");

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"Files\filename.png", fileBytes);

    }
}
```

Comment: The request is failing, not the act of reading the bytes afterwards.

Comment: Like James mentioned, your request is failing. The server is responding with a 406 (Not Acceptable) error. You're likely not using the correct URL (including http vs https), or the host is not allowing the download.

Comment: The Url is correct. if i type it into a browser i get the desired file.
Executing a get request in postman works aswell.

Comment: Check to see how the headers differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like the webserver hosting the files didnt like not having the User-Agent attribute set.
After setting it, the request worked.